# How often does Android refresh the battery statistics listed in the Settings?

Tags: settings, battery

Does anyone know how often Android refreshes battery statistics? This screen is `Settings > Battery`. This may only apply to Android versions >4.0.

Comment: final: it took me 1 minute to get my app visible in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is real-time. Meaning, the stats are always updated as the battery is being drained (or charged).

Comment: To my knowledge it is. And the term "battery stats" might be a bit misleading here -- it's rather a statistic on how/which apps "sucked on it" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [source code of battery history](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9a7debe5857ffc7c71cfc4082b1b6d72a5cf81cd/core/java/android/os/BatteryStats.java) and [battery history part of Settings](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge). I hadn't got time to properly check it out, but from an initial scan, I think it's updated every time the app is started. The file from which the app generates the statistic however, batterystats.bin, is probably collected at real time as the system starts and kills apps and system services are turned on and off.

Comment: first link says at line 323 `Returns the total time (in 1/100 sec) spent executing in user code.` I think this is it, right?

Comment: @Lumma: I believe that's referring to [real/user/sys time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1)